# Eclipse - reload microcontroller image without session termination

Tags: eclipse, arm, microcontroller, stm32, openocd

Using OpenOCD and Eclipse for debugging ARM (for ex. STM32) is there any option to reload image without session termination?

If you are debuging uC directly by gdb and OpenOCD you can simply type `load` once again.

(to specify we can consider gnu-arm-eclipse plugin)

Comment: what do you mean by session termination?  in order to get in/through the processor using the ocd you need to stop the processor then the debugger can use the processors bus to access for example the flash.  then you can restart the processor or reset it your choice.  the further away you get from the debugger the less choices perhaps you have for example using gdb rather than telnet to talk to openocd, using a stock config file that might reset the processor and halt when you connect or other things you may not like.

Comment: what specifically do you want it to do and what specifically is it doing?

Comment: @old_timer Is there any  shortcut or gui button to reload image? I know I can do it from terminal as I used to, but I found debugging from eclipse much more confortable (except reloading image). What I have to do now to reload image? I have to terminate debugging session and start it again, because during startup the image is loaded to uC.